# Is there a way to implement a popup when an user uninstalls your wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am relatively new to wordpress plugin development and I have read through the wordpress codex but outside of best practices and simple example of the uninstall functionality I am not getting much in the way of what the plugin can do when the user actually uninstalls it.

What I am looking to achieve is when an user uninstalls my plugin a popup appears asking them if they want to just remove the plugin files or the plugin files and all of the content the plugin has uploaded to their site. For a bit more context my plugin's primary function is to migrate data stored on a separate server into the user's instance of wordpress as posts and those posts are what I am looking to remove if the user selects that option.

Below is my current setup for the uninstall and when I click uninstall in wordpress, wordpress does uninstall my plugin(removes the plugin folder and files from its directory) but the popup isn't displaying during this process. I originally thought it was a styling issue but the HTML in the popup file isn't being loaded. I have also checked the file path variable and it's the correct path. So I am not sure what is preventing the popup from being displayed and allowing the user to select whether or not the content should be deleted along with the plugin or not.

Any help or insight in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

uninstall.php

```
<?php
//checks to make sure Wordpress is the one requesting the uninstall
if (!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN')) {
    die;
}
$my_plugin_file_path = trailingslashit(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

include $my_plugin_file_path . 'templates/my-plugin-uninstall-popup.php';
```

my-plugin-uninstall-popup.php

```
<!-- styling for popup -->
<!-- end of styling for popup -->
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Uninstall popup</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $my_plugin_file_path . 'my-plugin-uninstall-executor.php' ); ?>" method="post">
                <label>Do you want to remove the content that this plugin has uploaded?</label>
                <input id="delete-content-yes" name="delete-content" value="YES" type="radio" />Yes
                <input id="delete-content-no" name="delete-content" value="NO" type="radio" />No
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my-plugin-uninstall-executor.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete-content']) && $_POST['delete-content'] === 'YES') 
    //delete content from user's wordpress db
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know at least, there's no official hook available to display a custom uninstall screen.

In older versions of WordPress there used to be an Uninstall confirmation screen -although I'm pretty sure there was no way to hook into it either- but nowadays WordPress simply shows a JS confirmation box ("*Are you sure you want to delete [Plugin Name] and its data?*") before running `uninstall.php` -if found- and deleting its files.

What I've seen other plugin developers do in this case is include a custom Uninstall screen in the plugin's Settings / Config page which allows them to do pretty much what you described in your question. It's not an ideal solution as some users might uninstall the plugin the "traditional" way if they're unaware of your custom Uninstall screen so you won't be able to show your confirmation screen/popup, but that's the best you can do at this time.

If you want to take it a step further [this answer tells you how to uninstall a plugin programatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/how-to-delete-the-hello-dolly-plugin-automatically). It's pretty old now (2011) but if that still works then maybe you could delete your own plugin after running your custom actions.

Comment: ...or with Settings screen user could just choose in advance "when plugins is uninstalled should we drop also all data migrated?"

Comment: Yep, that would be a good idea. Maybe ask the user about it as a part of the initial plugin setup? (with the option to change that later if needed).

Answer (score 1):

```
do_action( 'pre_uninstall_plugin', function( $plugin ) {
    if ( $plugin === 'path to your main plugin file from plugins directory' ) {
        wp_redirect( 'url of your custom uninstall script' );
        exit();
    }
} );
```

This will abort the builtin wordPress uninstall code and your custom uninstall script can do anything you want but of course you will need to implement quite a bit of code and this would be difficult if you do not know WordPress well but if you do this you will learn quite a bit on how WordPress works in admin mode.

ADDENDUM

On further thought I think this can be done quite easily. Your custom script should show your form in a custom admin page. Submitting this form can save your settings in transients in the wp_options table and then redirect to the original delete URL. In the action 'pre_uninstall_plugin' if the transients exists then do nothing and let WordPress call your uninstall script. Of course your uninstall script should read your settings from the transients in the wp_options table and process accordingly. Redirecting back to the original delete URL will let WordPress handle the generic part of deleting your plugin and your uninstall script needs to handle only the plugin specific part of deleting your plugin. If this delete was done as part of a bulk delete request then before redirecting you should clean the original delete URL by removing previously deleted plugins.

ADDENDUM to ADDENDUM

In fact it is possible to do even better. The basic idea is to intercept the plugin delete request, do a HTTP redirect to a page that configures the delete request, saves the delete configuration to the database and then do a HTTP redirect to the original delete request. When the plugin's uninstall script is called it reads its delete configuration from the database and deletes accordingly. In this case the interception should be done as early as possible so action 'admin_init' would be a good choice. The advantage to early interception is if the plugin is being deleted as part of a bulk request since the interception is done before anything has been processed the original delete URL is still valid and you do not need to worry about previously deleted plugins.

There is quite a lot of code to write to implement this solution which I do not have the time to do but I can give you an outline of what to do.

1. Using add_submenu_page() create an admin page to configure the uninstall for your plugin. Although this page will be invoked by a HTTP redirect, admin pages are invoked via a hook and this hook requires an entry in the global $menu. add_submenu_page() is used here only to create an entry in the global $menu for the function that will display the admin page. The menu item that is also created is not needed and can be hidden.
2. Using an action on 'admin_init' intercept delete requests for your plugin. The delete request looks like this.

   http://aaa.bbb.ccc/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=delete-selected&checked[0]=your-plugin-path.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=027649d7ff

You can use $_SERVER and $_GET global variables to help you parse the request URL. (The global $pagenow may be useful here.) If the request is a delete request for your plugin. Use wp_redirect() to do a HTTP redirect to the admin page you created using add_submenu_page(). You need to pass the original URL after encoding using urlencode to your admin page as a query parameter. The URL of your admin page looks like this.

```
http://aaa.bbb.ccc/wp-admin/admin.php?page=your-settings-page
```

You can get this URL from the menu item as it is just the href of a HTML A element.

3. Your handler for your admin page should show your settings form for configuring the uninstall of your plugin. You can pass the original delete URL as a hidden input field so when submitting this form it will also send the original delete URL.
4. The handler for the submitted form should use set_transient() to save the settings as transients in the database. Then it should do a wp_redirect() to the original delete URL.
5. The 'admin_init' handler will be called again and should check if the transients have been set and if they have been set do nothing and let WordPress handle the delete request.
6. Your uninstall script should read the transients from the database and process accordingly and then remove the transients from the database.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response though I am having a bit of trouble implementing it. I am getting the html of my form showing up now but it is an admin-notice. Wordpress is stripping out the functionality/styling of the form. I am pretty sure I am haven't correctly implemented your solution so would it be possible to see an example of what you are describing in your solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of an admin notice I would try an admin page. Unfortunately, neither really looks like a popup which would have been ideal. To be honest, I have not actually implemented this solution and thought about it only because it seemed like an interesting problem. There is quite a bit of code to write and I have some other things I need to work on right now. AFAIK it is possible to style the admin notices so I think you can get that to work. I think an admin page is preferable as it would really focus the user on the setting the configuration and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use jQuery to intercept the click on the 'delete' HTML A element and display your form instead. Then use an AJAX request to save your delete settings in transients in the wp_options table. When the AJAX request returns you can then forward to the original delete URL. Your uninstall script needs to read the delete settings previously saved in the transients.

This approach involves less code but is dependent on the specific HTML implementation of the HTML delete element (currently a HTML A element with class 'delete'). Since, WordPress can change this implementation this approach is not safe with respect to upgrades. Of course, this will not work with bulk deletes but in that case you could intercept the bulk delete action and show your form and proceed as before.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using javascript and ajax. Javascript catches the click asks if you want to delete data if so it calls delete the data ajax in either case it continues to the deactivate.

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'deactivate_message_enqueue');
function deactivate_message_enqueue($hook) {
    if ( 'plugins.php' != $hook ) {
        // do not enqueue because it is not plugins page
        return;
    }

    wp_register_script('deactivation-message', plugins_url('includes/js/message_deactivate.js', __FILE__), array(), SOW_VERSION);
    
    $deleteParams = array(
        'ajax_url'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'ajax_nonce'    => wp_create_nonce('nonce_salt'),
    );
    wp_localize_script('deactivation-message', 'deactivation_data', $deleteParams);
    wp_enqueue_script('deactivation-message');
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_hss_so_delete_all_tables', 'hssSoDeleteAllTablesAjax' );
function hssSoDeleteAllTablesAjax() {
  global $wpdb;
  
  // need to check nonce so it is secure.
  $nonce = isset($_REQUEST['security']) ? sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['security']) : '';

  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'nonce_salt' ) ) {
    wp_send_json_error(array('error' => 'Nonce invalid'));
  }

  // delete what you have to here
  wp_send_json_success(array('error' => ''));

}
```

Then in the script file catch the url redirect of the deactivate and call ajax function to delete the data

*includes/js/message_deactivate.js*

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.querySelector('[data-slug="plugin-slug"] .deactivate a').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var urlRedirect = document.querySelector('[data-slug="plugin-slug"] .deactivate a').getAttribute('href');
    if(confirm('Do you want to delete all the data created for this plugin?')) {
        deleteAllPluginData();
    }
    window.location.href = urlRedirect;
  })
}

function deleteAllPluginData(){
var data = 'action=delete_all_my_plugin_data&security=' + deactivation_data.ajax_nonce;

jQuery.ajax({
    type : "post",
    dataType : "json",
    url : deactivation_data.ajax_url,
    data : data,
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.success == true) {
            console.log('All Data Deleted.');
        } else {
            console.log('There was an error deleting data: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data.error));
        }
    },
});
```

}